# PHP Sum the values of duplicate keys in ONE array

Tags: php, arrays

i could not find an exactly similar question so here it is

Given an array...

```
print_r( $givenArray );
```

Will output this:

```
array (
    [A] => 1
    [B] => 0
    [A] => 3
    [C] => 4
);
```

I need to sum values of the same keys, so the result will look like this

```
array(
    [A] => 4
    [B] => 0
    [C] => 4
);
```

How is that possible? thanks

**UPD (after the ozthgreat's comment) :**

```
[0] => array( 
    [name] => array( 
        [0] => "A", 
        [1] => "B",
        [2] => "C" ) 
    [count] => array( 
        [0] => 1, 
        [1] => 0, 
        [2] => 4 ) ),
[1] => array( 
    [name] => array(
        [0] => "A", 
        [1] => "C") 
    [count] => array(
        [0] => 3, 
        [1] => 4))
```

the 'original' array looks like this...They array before update looks stupid because i tried `array_count_values` and `array_combine` and came to that look

Comment: it is impossible :) array cant has the same keys

Comment: Array keys in PHP have to be unique, you can't have an array as per your first example I'm afraid.

Comment: yes, you are right, the original array looks like this(i just didnt figure it out how to do it here): `[0] => array( [name] => array( [0] => "A", [1] => "B" [2] => "C" ) [count] => array( [0] => 1, [1] => 0, [2] => 4 ) ), [1] => array( [name] => array([0] => "A", [1] => "C") [count] => array([0] => 3, [1] => 4))`

I will edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/*
You can test with these values:
$givenArray = array(
    array(
        'name' => array('A', 'B', 'C'),
        'count' => array(1, 0, 4),
    ),
    array(
        'name' => array('A', 'C'),
        'count' => array(3, 4),
    )
);
*/

$newArray = array();
// New datas will be put in this new array.

foreach($givenArray as $nameAndCount) {
    foreach($nameAndCount['name'] as $index => $name) {
        if (!isset($newArray[$name])) {
        // Init $newArray[A] for example
            $newArray[$name] = 0;
        }

        $newArray[$name] += $nameAndCount['count'][$index];
        // Add the right 'count' to $newArray[A]
    }
}


/*
Output:
Array
(
    [A] => 4
    [B] => 0
    [C] => 8
)
*/
```

Answer (score -2):

This is not tested, but try this:

```
$newArray = array();

foreach ($givenArray as $key => $value){
    // If the array key already exists in the new array
    if(array_key_exists($key,$newArray)){
        // overwrite the element, adding the looped value
        $newArray[$key] = $newArray[$key] + $value; 
    } else {
        // add the element and value to the new array
        $newArray[$key] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump($newArray);
```

Comment: As `$givenArray` can't exist in the form that the OP has shown, this is a pretty meaningless answer.... unless `$givenArray` is an iterable object or a generator

Comment: Clearly you are correct, although `$givenArray` is presumably a pseudonym for the real OP's data, in which case, seeing an example, looping through an array, checking that a key exists, and overwriting or adding a key based on this decision, may help the OP to find a solution.  Surely we are here to help and encourage.. ..not critisize?

Comment: As `$newArray` is an empty array at the beginning of your code, `array_key_exists($key,$newArray)` can't be true here. (Keys all come from a single array, `$givenArray`.)